# Vue $emit not firing inside parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For some reason my $emit doesn't seem to be firing inside the parent. I am basically trying to create a modal popup for a html form. Inside my header component I have a button that fires $emit I then try to listen to this event inside my app.js on the form component. But the form component is doing nothing when the emit is fired.

Here's my code

client/src/app.js

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <MainHeader :modalVisability="modal" />
        <OppForm :modalVisability="modal" v-on:showModal="modal = $event"/>

        <div>{{ modal }}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import MainHeader from './components/MainHeader.vue';
import OppForm from './components/oppForm.vue';

export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
        MainHeader,
        OppForm
    },
    data() {
        return {
            modal: false
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

client/components/MainHeader.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="main_header_wrap">
        <header>
            <button v-on:click="showOppForm">Add Post</button>
        </header>

        <div>{{ modalVisability }}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            modalVisability: Boolean
        },
        methods: {
            showOppForm() {
                this.modalVisability = true;
                this.$emit('showModal', this.modalVisability);
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

client/src/components/oppForm.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="opp_form" >
        <form @submit.prevent="SubmitOpp" v-if="modalVisability">
            <input type="text" name="company_name" v-model="company_name">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

        <div>{{ modalVisability }}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        name: 'oppForm',
        props: {
            modalVisability: Boolean,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                company_name: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            SubmitOpp() {
                axios.post('http://localhost:5000/', {
                    company_name: this.company_name,
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Try using `@showModal` instead of `v-on:showModal`

Comment: Try to add a handler like `v-on:showModal="show"` and `methods:{show(e){this.modal=e;}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed somethings in your code. See the example below:

client/src/app.js

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <MainHeader :modalVisability="modal" @showModal="changeModal" />
    <OppForm :modalVisability="modal" />
    <div>App = {{ modal }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MainHeader from './components/MainHeader.vue';
import OppForm from './components/oppForm.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: { MainHeader, OppForm },
  data() {
    return {
      modal: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeModal(newValueModal) {
      this.modal = newValueModal;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

client/components/MainHeader.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id="main_header_wrap">
    <header>
      <button v-on:click="showOppForm">Add Post</button>
    </header>
    <div>MainHeader = {{ modalVisability }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    modalVisability: Boolean,
  },
  methods: {
    showOppForm() {
      this.$emit('showModal', !this.modalVisability);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

client/src/components/oppForm.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id="opp_form">
    <form @submit.prevent="SubmitOpp" v-if="modalVisability">
      <input type="text" name="company_name" v-model="company_name" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div>oppForm = {{ modalVisability }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'oppForm',
  props: {
    modalVisability: Boolean,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      company_name: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    SubmitOpp() {
      axios
        .post('http://localhost:5000/', {
          company_name: this.company_name,
        })
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

1 - App.js: Listen the event in `MainHeader` component.

2 - App.js: `OppForm` don't need to listen the event, because this component don't change the `modal` value.

3 - MainHeader.vue: Avoid to change the props value.

Comment: Thanks. Just a couple questions if you don't mind. Do you always have to listen to the event on the component that called it? and is the value returned from the emit automatically passed into the changeModal function? also thanks for point 3. I was wondering how to fix that error

Comment: `o you always have to listen to the event on the component that called it?` Answer: Yes

Comment: `and is the value returned from the emit automatically passed into the changeModal function?` Answer: Yes